# Backbone Model and idAttribute when updating record

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working with mongoLab and the model id looks like this

```
"_id": {
  "$oid": "50f9a0f5e4b007f27f766cf3"
},
```

I am using the `idAttribute` to set the model id to `_id` and everything works fine until I attempt to update the model.

Because the `_id` attribute exists in the model, I am getting an error when I attempt to insert.

Do I need to remove the attribute `_id` from my attributes? I was under the assumption that the magic of Backbone would clean up the attributes appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to remove the `_id` attribute.

In the MongoLab REST API, the id isn't part of the data payload itself, but that isn't the case for all backends.  It probably makes more sense for Backbone to assume that the id should be present in the payload, than it would to assume it should not.

That being said there's no real *nice* way to get Backbone to clean the id from the payload automatically.  Your best bet without monkeypatching/rewriting too much of the code would probably be to override `Model#toJSON`, something akin to:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON = function (options) {
  var attrs = _.clone(this.attributes);
  // In this case you'd have to pass `includeId: true` to `toJSON` when you
  // actually *want* the _id in the output.
  return options && options.includeId ? attrs : _.omit(attrs, '_id');
};
```

You could also monkeypatch sync, something like:

```
var sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function (method, model, options) {
  options || (options = {});
  // if options.attrs is present, Backbone will use it over dumping toJSON
  if (!options.attrs) options.attrs = _.omit(model.attributes, '_id');
  return sync.call(Backbone, method, model, options);
};
```

Comment: was not complete solution, I needed to add a functionality in the `Model.parse` function to convert the `_id` into a unique property, the string representation of the JSON object returned from mongoLab REST API call was being converted by default to the string `[Object]` so only one item was returned in the collection

Comment: This makes sense.  And after looking at [their spec for extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json), I'd say that overriding both `Model#parse` and `Model#toJSON` is definitely the right approach.  Depending on your usage you might want to implement packing/unpacking for some of the other data types as well.  It seems a little strange that someone hasn't done this in a small lib.  I didn't find anything with a cursory search.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue where _id translated to null when in javascript..
had to do something like..

```
 var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   parse: function(response){
     var response = response.whatever;
     response.id = response.null;
     delete response.null;
     return appointment;
     }
  });
```

or for a collection

```
systems.forEach(function(system){
    console.log(system);
    system.id = system.null;
    delete system.null;
});
```